# Map json object to java object (but my json object variables has first letter capital)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, objectmapper

I have a third party API that gives response as JSON object whose variables has first letter capital
My JSON object looks like this:

```json
{
   "ApiStatus":{
      "ApiStatusCode":5000,
      "ApiMessage":"OK",
      "FWStatusCode":0,
      "FWMessage":""
   },
   "Encounter":{
      "EncounterId":"hgasfdjsdgkf",
      "ApiLinks":[
         {
            "Title":"Self",
            "Description":"Self referencing api",
            "ResourceName":"self",
            "HttpMethods":[
               "GET",
               "DELETE"
            ],
            "URL":"http://www.google.com/api/v2/test/test2/hchvjh"
         },
         {
            "Title":"Transmit a Report",
            "Description":"Create a report and transmit it.",
            "ResourceName":"transmitter",
            "HttpMethods":[
               "POST"
            ],
            "URL":"http://www.google.com/api/v2/test3/test3/jydgfkshd/transmitter"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see above variable's first letter is capital and need to map that in My java object class, so when I tried to use `ObjectMapper`, but it's not working.

```
MyJavaObject object = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonObject, MyJavaObject.class);
```

Any Suggestion or help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the default naming strategy for Jackson to be `UpperCamelCaseStrategy` as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy);
MyJavaObject object = objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, MyJavaObject.class);
```

For the properties `URL`, `FWStatusCode` and `FWMessage`, which do not follow camel case, snake case or any other naming strategy, you will you need to use `@JsonProperty` on your class attributes so that Jackson knows how to handle them. Just annotate the class attribute with the respective `@JsonProperty` and it will work:

- `@JsonProperty("URL")`
- `@JsonProperty("FWStatusCode")`
- `@JsonProperty("FWMessage")`

Comment: Used your code 

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
MyJavaObject object = objectMapper.readValue(response, MyJavaObject.class);
All variables are mapped except URL and FWStatusCode and FWMessage.

Did I do it right or any other changes required.

Comment: I didn't notice those 3. For them, you need to use `@JsonProperty` on your class attributes so that Jackson knows how to handle them. The reason is that they do not follow camel case, snake case or any other naming strategy. Use `@JsonProperty("URL")`, `@JsonProperty("FWStatusCode")` and `@JsonProperty("FWMessage")` on the respective class attribute and it will work.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!